# Function returning every binary number until certain value

Tags: python

I have this function:

```
def binary_numbers(a):
    for x in range(1, a):
        return bin(x)
```

I want this to print every binary number from 0 to `my_input` on this command.

```
print binary_numbers(my_input)
```

So if I write 5 as the argument I want it to print

```
0b0
0b1
0b10
0b11
0b100
0b101
```

However, when I call it with 5 this what I get:

```
>>> print binary_numbers(5)
'0b1'
```

can anyone explain me why?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Based on the fact that you're posting on SO, something's going wrong. If you tell us what error you are getting, we'll have a better chance of helping

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that, your function returns right after processing the first number (because the control reaches the `return` statement)

Four ways to fix this

1. Print immediately

   ```
   def binary_numbers(a):
       for x in range(1, a):
           return bin(x)    # Dont return here, instead print bin(x)

   binary_numbers(5)
   ```
2. Construct a list with comprehension and return it

   ```
   def binary_numbers(a):
       return [bin(x) for x in range(1, a)]
   ```
3. Construct a list, with `map` function like this

   ```
   def binary_numbers(a):
       return map(bin, range(1, a))
   ```
4. Create a generator, with `yield` keyword like this

   ```
   def binary_numbers(a):
       for x in range(1, a):
           yield bin(x)
   for current_binary_number in binary_numbers(5):
       print current_binary_number
   ```

Answer (score 0):

On the off chances that where you're stuck is in actually *getting* `"my_input"`:

---

You have two choices, depending on your larger application.

Ask for it when you need it:

```
def binary_numbers(a):
    for x in range(1, a):
        yield bin(x)

a = int(raw_input('My Input: '))
print list(binary_numbers(a))
```

Or pass it as a command line argument: `> python binary_number.py 5`:

```
import sys
def binary_numbers(a):
    for x in range(1, a):
        yield bin(x)

a = int(sys.argv[1])
print list(binary_numbers(a))
```

You have other choices, like reading from a file, but these are the interactive ones.

**Note:** I've also changed your return to a yield and printed the list representation of your function call.